# Shorthand syntax for message-attributes in the send-message command in aws-cli for sqs

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sqs

When trying to send a message using AWS CLI for SQS, I cannot get the shorthand syntax for the `--message-attributes` parameter to work.

Specifying a json file works fine, and the reference doesn't show an example for the shorthand option.

Here is the reference for this command which specifies the shorthand I'm trying to use but I can't get it to work: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sqs/send-message.html

Here's the command I've tried:

```
aws sqs send-message \
--queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/0000000000/aa_queue_name \
--message-body "message body goes here" \
--message-attributes firstAttribute={DataType=String,StringValue="hello world"},secondAttribute={DataType=String,StringValue="goodbye world"}
```

I keep getting error messages:

> Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter
>   MessageAttributes.contentType, value: StringValue=Snapshot, type:
>   , valid types:

Anyone ever managed sending attributes for message using the shorthand?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Your Shorthand Syntax format is correct:

> **MY_KEY**={DataType=**String**, StringValue=**MY_VALUE**}

You just forgot to enclose the commandline option with single or double quotes:

```
aws sqs send-message \
  --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/0000000000/aa_queue_name \
  --message-body "message body goes here" \
  --message-attributes 'firstAttribute={DataType=String, StringValue="hello world"}, secondAttribute={DataType=String,StringValue="goodbye world"}'
```

The above shortcut syntax should correctly produce a message with 2 extra headers, a.k.a. Message Attributes:

```
firstAttribute=hello world
secondAttribute=goodbye world
```

---

## NOTE:

an attribute is a `<class 'dict'>`, so every attribute looks like a dictionary: `{DataType=String, StringValue=MY_VALUE}`,

- where supported `DataType`s are **String**, **Number**, or
  **Binary**.
- each DataType value can contain an optional custom extention, that is ignored by AWS. For example: **String.uuid**, **Number.int**,
  **Binary.pdf**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html#message-attribute-components

Answer (score 25):

Currently, the documentation of the short-hand syntax for the `--message-attributes` option is incorrect and the short-hand syntax does not work.

Instead, you can use the JSON file (as you mentioned). You can also use the inline JSON:

```
aws sqs send-message 
  --queue-url https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/0000000000/aa_queue_name 
  --message-body "message body goes here" 
  --message-attributes '{ "firstAttribute":{ "DataType":"String","StringValue":"hello world" }, "secondAttribute":{ "DataType":"String","StringValue":"goodbye world"} }'
```

Comment: This answer provides a valid JSON style workaround but doesn't answer the original "Short-hand style" question. It shouldn't be the accepted one. @epox 's answer demonstrates the "short-hand syntax" usage. The latter answer should be accepted.